# TFS Adjust process Bug Tempate - Sevirty

Tags: templates, tfs

I am trying to adjust the Bug forms "Severity" to have a new custom field value on creation of "new" (currently it shows 3 of a 1 to 5 choice) however I cant find any specific examples of how to do this , e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-modify-wit does not go into detail  We want to explicitly show that the severity has not explicitly been set yet.

=> Tips or Urls please ?

Below is the default content from a "witadmin exportprocessconfig" command. I am on TFs 2017 up3

```
<BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" pluralName="Bugs" singularName="Bug">
 <States>
  <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
  <State type="Proposed" value="Approved" />
  <State type="InProgress" value="Committed" />
  <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
</States>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the `Bug.xml` file to add a new LISTITEM in `Severity` field rule. Check the example below:

```
<FieldDefinition name=" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <DEFAULT from="value" value="3 - Medium" />
  <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
    <LISTITEM value="1 - Critical" />
    <LISTITEM value="2 - High" />
    <LISTITEM value="3 - Medium" />
    <LISTITEM value="4 - Low" />
    <LISTITEM value="5 - NewCustom" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
</FieldDefinition>
```